# Querying varying JSON strings in AWS Redshift

Tags: sql, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Is there a way in AWS Redshift to query all key/value pairs from a JSON string where each record has a different number of key/value pairs?

I.e. in the below example, the first animal has the 'location' attribute whereas the second does not. Using the [`json_extract_path_text`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT.html) function I can pick out attributes I know exist for both records but when trying to query the location it will fail:

```
   create table test.jsondata(json varchar(65000));
    insert into  test.jsondata(json) values ('{ "animal_id": 1, "name": "harry", "animal_type": "cat", "age": 2, "location": "oakland"}');
    insert into  test.jsondata(json) values ('{ "animal_id": 2, "name": "louie","animal_type": "dog", "age": 4}');

    select 
      json_extract_path_text(JSON,'animal_id') animal_id,
      json_extract_path_text(JSON,'name') name,
      json_extract_path_text(JSON,'animal_type') animal_type,
      json_extract_path_text(JSON,'age') age,
      json_extract_path_text(JSON,'location') location
    from test.jsondata
    order by animal_id;
```

> ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near "location"

Desired Outcome:

```
animal_id name animal_type age location
1 harry cat 2 oakland
2 louie dog 4 NULL
```

Comment: extra `,` after location

Comment: @vkp sorry yes updated query. Even without the trailing comma though I get the same error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that that json_extract_path_text works with `ISNULL`:

```
select 
      json_extract_path_text(JSON,'animal_id') animal_id,
      json_extract_path_text(JSON,'name') name,
      json_extract_path_text(JSON,'animal_type') animal_type,
      json_extract_path_text(JSON,'age') age,
      ISNULL(json_extract_path_text(JSON,'location'),NULL) location
    from test.jsondata
    order by animal_id;
```